# Does it matter whether or not you call exit after a header("Location: ") call?

Tags: php

I couldn't seem to find an answer until I found [this post](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exit.php#90713) on `exit` over at php.net.

> After sending the `Location:' header PHP *will* continue parsing, and all code below the header() call will still be executed.

Is this valid?

And to further this question, if it is valid, to what benefit does it have to leave `exit` out (and let the rest of the code run)?

Comment: was already written 2 years ago: http://thephpcode.blogspot.com/2009/01/why-exit-after-header-redirect.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, that is valid. The header() function just sends a header to the browser along with the rest of your page which tells the browser to redirect. If you don't want the script to continue running then you should do an `exit` or `die`.

There may be cases where you want the script to continue running though as well, depending on the script. You may be keeping track of page hits or something and you might have code insert that into a database included at the bottom of every page. If you want it to track the hit before the redirect then you wouldn't want to `exit` early.

Another case you might want to continue running the code is if you have a timed redirect header, and want to display something to the user like `Redirect to: http://xxxxxx in 5 seconds`. So they have a chance to see where their browser's going before the redirect. You would probably only want to do that if you were redirecting them to an entirely different website though.

In most cases you do want to `exit` because you do not likely want to output anything to the browser in that case and the extra code will just slow down your redirect.

Comment: So if I'm using the `header()` function as a redirect but don't use `exit`, the browser will wait to redirect until it finishes running through the rest of the code?

Comment: You might want to note that to keep code running that actually does important stuff, one might want to set `ignore_user_abort(true);`

Comment: @Wex: depends on the user-agent. Some might, most won't.

Comment: Yeah, headers do get sent first, so if the browser redirects immediately and your server is configured to quit scripts when the user leaves the page early then you would want to `ignore_user_abort(true);` I prefer to have my server always ignore user abort because I don't want the script to stop halfway if it has database queries and the like in it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is valid, because headers are sent with another content. Script executes and AFTER that content&headers are sent to user.