# PHP header not keeping query string

Tags: php, string, header

I have a strange issue. It almost seems like a bug.

`if ($object->error) {Form::BuildReturn(); header ("location:$url");}`

Now if I echo the value of $url, I get the correct value: `/projects/view/112/?edit-note=105`

But when the script executes, it takes me to `/projects/view/112/`.

Here's the weird part though: I can try to echo or print something right after the header and then it will take me to `/projects/view/112/?edit-note=105` like I want it to. Example:

`if ($object->error) {Form::BuildReturn(); header ("location:$url"); echo 0;}`

I've tried searching this for about half an hour now using terms like 'PHP header query string', 'PHP header get values', and so on. I hope there is some actual solution to this rather than using a hacky workaround that generates 'cannot modify header information' warnings...

Comment: Seems like `header("Location:...")` doesn't accept Get variables. Does it work if you directly write "/projects/view..." in PHP instead of $url? Maybe you could try adding `exit;` after the redirection if it works with echo.

Comment: Doh... didn't even think of `exit;`... that worked. Thank you. If you post that as an answer I will accept it.

Comment: Try an absolute URL, including protocol and server name `http://example.com/..` -- Also show a `wget -S` or Firebug header dump. Also likely you have multiple header() calls in your code, one overwriting the more specific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding `exit;` after redirecting. That stops executing the current file.

Answer (score 2):

Add

```
exit(0);
```

after the header for the redirect.

Because the code continues to run even after the header call. You need to explicitly exit the script for the redirect. This is discussed more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6784586/does-it-matter-whether-or-not-you-call-exit-after-a-headerlocation-call).

Answer (score 1):

The correct syntax is:

```
header("Location: $url");
```

There's a space in there and a capital L, I'm not sure that'll make much difference.

For the moment I'd suggest doing some low level debugging. Use `wget`, `curl`, the developer mode in your browser or a plugin that will echo all of the HTTP headers and then post up exactly what's being returned in the server headers (if the results don't allow  you to figure it out anyway).

Answer (score 1):

You should always `exit` after you pass a `Location` header, to prevent the rest of the page from showing. Also, it should fix your problem.

---

Also, the correct form of the `Location` header would be:

```
header("Location: $url"); //Has space and capital L
```

I don't think it would matter really, only for older browsers maybe?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a redirection function with meta tag. That will keep query string

```
function redir($url, $time = 0) {
  echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="', $time, ';URL=', $url, '">';
  die;
}
```

Comment: but that always takes some time and is client-sided.